# How can we change the background of the desktop via filing?

Tags: background, c

I  wish to change the background of my computer by doing filing in C language but I dont have any idea how to proceed in this regard.Please guide me to the files i must open and what changes must i do to them

Comment: @fahad: What's your environment (OS, etc.)? Anyway, maybe this question is more affine to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: @cYrus: Sorry, my bad! And I also vote to move it on SO

Comment: I too think it´s better asked on SO

Comment: Wrong forum... that should be on StackOverflow....

Comment: I am using windows(XP)  and my compiler is old turbo C

Comment: Turbo C? Forget it. There are excellent Win32/64 C compilers for free such as Pelles C.

Answer (score 2):

That is highly OS specific and so not worth the effort to do it in C because for each environment you support you will have to do a lot of code but of course, it's up to you to choose.

In linux you have several tools available and you can look at their source-code.
I believe it even depends on the type of graphic environment you're in. For gnome there is gconftool-2, for KDE you have to look yourself but it's easy to find.
For linux it would be wiser to do a system call like:

```
char str[] = "gconftool-2 -t str --set /desktop/gnome/background/picture_filename /path_to_your/pic.png"; // adapt it
system(str);
```

instead of writing code from scratch.

For windows there is a very short batch script here that should be easy to convert:
[batch - change background](http://www.windowsitpro.com/article/tips/q-how-can-a-batch-script-alter-the-users-screen-saver-and-wallpaper-settings-and-become-effective-without-a-logoff-and-logon-.aspx).
To do it in C you write the strings to a text file with the extension .reg then do a system call to apply it.

For Mac OS it's different too, so you have to be more specific